# Xpath query, making a certain query more generic

Tags: xpath

I'm trying to extract information from Wikipedia tables.

More specifically, I'm trying to make a list of all teams and all players in the premier league.

Until now I'm able to traverse over the whole teams in the premier league 2019-2020 table of teams, for every team there I get in it Wikipedia page and traverse over its player's getting their information.

I thought there is a fixed template that all premier league teams in Wikipedia have their table of players at position 3 but after traversing 6 teams it faced a team that it's table is in 2nd place.

So I was using the following XPath query on every team wiki page

```
"//table[3]/tbody//tr[position() > 1]//td[4]//span/a/@href"
```

but for example, the following team players table is at position 2, how can I make this query more generic and not fix it a certain position? I have noticed that all of my relevant tables have an  element before it with the text "First-team squad"

The HTML of the table is too long, so I post here the wiki link of a certain team

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_Palace_F.C.

Hope to get help! thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use another "anchor" which works for each page. The table you need is always the first after the span element "Players".

So with this :

```
//span[@id='Players']/following::table[1]//span[@class="fn"]//text()
```

You'll get the names of all players of the current squad team.

With this :

```
//span[@id='Players']/following::table[1]//span[@class="fn"]//@href
```

You'll get the associated URLs. /!\ Some players don't have a wikipedia webpage.
So you can have 26 player names but 25 urls. Like here :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chelsea_F.C.